# How to fix the scroll when increasing the width?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, frontend

I need that as the width increases, the elements inside remain in place. For some reason, this does not always happen, sometimes the scroll starts moving to the right.
How to fix the scroll when increasing the width?

```
 <reactResizable.ResizableBox
        className="box"
        width={200}
        height={200}
        axis="x"
        resizeHandles={["e"]}
      >
        <div className="inner">
          {Array.from(generateSequence(1, 6)).map((e) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <span className="text">BLOCK {e}</span>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </reactResizable.ResizableBox>
```

```
.box {
  background: white;
  overflow: auto hidden;
}

.box .react-resizable-handle-e {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(0);
  top: 0;
}

.inner {
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: overlay;
}

.inner > div {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/xDSUP-the-selector/pen/JjZBRXM)
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0f7F.gif)

I tried to debug it. I don't understand why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Instead of increasing width for **box react-resizable** class container. Increase the width for **inner** container. It will work

Comment: It is work. But there is a new problem: resizeHandler moves when scrolling when it is in the same container with the content of the resizerBox